# compareTo()==0 isn't working

Tags: java, compareto

I'm using compareTo() in a doubly-linked-list to compare a code and a read string, and can't figure out why it isn't working. It's a lot of code involved, but I don't want to make you guys read through it all, so I'll try to post just what is relevant and hope it's enough.

This is the line of code. I know it's incomplete, but everything else is working properly.

```
if(p.getCode().compareTo(str)==0){
```

And they ARE equal. I printed them out the right before this comparison happens and they are the same.

I know not much has been given, and I'm kind of asking you to trust me that they really are equal, but it's to save you time. I'm wondering whether there is some sort of special rules I should know about regarding compareTo() I am missing...

Thanks.

Comment: I would print results of p.getCode().compareTo(str) before proceeding further just to make sure it is returning 0 OR not.

Comment: Try using `p.getCode().equals(str)`

Comment: I ask you to tell us the types and contents of both objects and the implementation of the compareTo() method if you wrote it.

Comment: Apparently they look equal to you when you print them out, but they are not according to the `Comparator`. Typical causes are trailing whitespace, which is not obvious from a `System.out.println` call.

Comment: +1 for @Robin comment, put apostrophes around your string when printing out

Comment: Are these both strings?  does p.getCode() return a string, or does it return an Integer or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compareTo` is provided by the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. There is no language enforced requirement that `Comparable.compareTo` return `0` when `Object.equals` returns `true`. That is, two instances of an object may be completely identical and an implementation of `Comparator.compareTo` does not have to return `0`.

Assuming that `p.getCode` returns a `String` and the argument `str` is a `String`, then the implementation of `String` does ensure that `equals` and `compareTo` are consistent.

So there are other possibilities:

1. You have leading or trailing spaces in one or both arguments. If you are going down the route of adding debug logging, I often find it helpful to use pipe ('|') characters around each string do that spaces will be visible.
2. There is a difference in uppercase vs. lowercase characters. String comparing is case sensitive and a special case-insensitive `Comparator` must be used.

Comment: True, but the documentation in String guarantees that.

Comment: True, but nothing in the question says p.getCode() is a string.

Comment: Maybe I'm not reading this right, but the first sentence is "I'm using compareTo() in a doubly-linked-list to compare a code and a read string". Sure, it could be that the code is not a string, but is that likely? If it is not a string then that is probably the problem.

Comment: To me, the question is this: `I'm wondering whether there is some sort of special rules I should know about regarding compareTo() I am missing...` ... so the OP seems to be asking about the generic behavior of `compareTo` and that is what I am providing.

Answer (score 1):

For testing equality, better use `equals()` instead of `compareTo()`. It's possible that there's a difference with the strings, maybe a trailing space, or some upper/lower case characters that don't match. To be extra-cautious, maybe something along these lines will help (assuming both strings are not null):

```
if (p.getCode().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(str.trim())) {
```

Now, if `p.getCode()` is not a `String` or `str` is not a `String` (you'll know this if the compiler complains that the method `trim()` doesn't exist for the object) ... there, you found the problem - you must make sure that both objects are of the same type before testing for equality.

Comment: `x.equals(y)` and `x.compareTo(y) == 0` are equivalent, where `x` and `y` are strings. This is a good comment (`equals` is the preferred approach), but not an answer.

Comment: @pst Yeah, but it will probably be *expanded* into an answer when more info becomes available. This answer just a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Are they both using the same encoding?  I've had issues before trying to compare ASCII and Unicode strings, particularly when parsing text files.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) `String.compareTo()` and `String.equals()` are consistent when it comes to equality

> The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

If you want to see the difference use [toCharArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) on both strings and print each character as ints.